# SQL Server: joins in one table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to extract data from SQL to an excel file, Here is sample data from the table.
The data exists in only one table and i cannot control the way data are inserted in it so cannot use joins between more one table.

```
 +------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
 |  ID  |              URL               |                TITLE                 |              LINKS_TO              |
 +------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
 | 1    | http://www.loc.gov/            | Library                              | http://www.loc.gov/library         |
 | 2    | http://www.loc.gov/library     | Catalog                              | NULL                               |
 | 3    | http://www.nasa.gov/           | NASA                                 | http://www.nasa.gov/images         |
 | 4    | http://www.nasa.gov/images     | National Institutes of Health (NIH)  | NULL                               |
```

I need to extract the ORIGINAL_URL and the TITLE of it's outlink(LINKS_TO) as in the output i put below. I tried joining the table to itself but the it got too complex for me. Here's the wanted output.

```
 +------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
 |          ORIGIN_URL          |                 TITLE                 |
 +------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
 | http://www.loc.gov/          | Catalog                               |
 | http://www.nasa.gov/         | National Institutes of Health (NIH)   |
```

Any help please?

Comment: School work? Show us your current attempt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `LEFT OUTER JOIN` this table with itself:

```
SELECT U.URL AS ORIGIN_URL,          
       Linked.TITLE
FROM dbo.URLs U
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.URLs Linked
   ON U.LINKS_TO = Linked.URL
```

Or use `INNER JOIN` if you only want those which are linked:

```
SELECT U.URL AS ORIGIN_URL,          
       Linked.TITLE
FROM dbo.URLs U
INNER JOIN dbo.URLs Linked
   ON U.LINKS_TO = Linked.URL
```

Comment: Thanks fo the answer. I tried to simplify the example but my table contain column families, let me add the code i used to create the table. CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TBL (ID VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, F.URL VARCHAR, P.TITLE VARCHAR, LINKS_TO VARCHAR); Can you tell me how the query should be with the column families?

Comment: @user2598997 Your `CREATE TABLE` statement does not contain a column `Families`.

Comment: @user2598997 . . . Tim answered your question.  If you have another question, you should ask it, providing more detail about what you really need.